# Access NSMutableArray from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

This is how my Entity classes look:

BaseDataEntity.h

```
#import -Foundation/Foundation.h

@interface BaseDataEntity : NSObject

@property (assign) NSMutableArray *cbxDataList;
@property (assign) NSString  *resaultText;

@end
```

BaseDataEntity.m

```
#import "BaseDataEntity.h"

@implementation BaseDataEntity

@synthesize cbxDataList = _cbxDataList;
@synthesize resaultText = _resaultText;

@end
```

And this is how I try to access them:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

    BaseDataEntity *aBaseDataEntity = [[BaseDataEntity alloc] init];
    [self setBaseDataEntity:aBaseDataEntity];

}

-(IBAction)ReadPort:(id)sender {

    NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %d", i];
        [array addObject:temp];
    }
    [self.baseDataEntity setCbxDataList:array];

    NSLog(@" cbxDataList count = %lu",[array count]);
    [array release];

    [self.baseDataEntity setResaultText:@"Test"];
    [self updateUserInterface:TRUE];
}


-(void)updateUserInterface:(BOOL)piClear{

    NSString *textValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"
                           ,[self.baseDataEntity resaultText]];

    if([self.ResaultTextField stringValue] != nil && !piClear){
        textValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", textValue
                     ,[self.ResaultTextField stringValue]];
    }

    NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:
        [self.baseDataEntity.cbxDataList value]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        textValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", textValue
                     ,[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    [array release];

    [self.ResaultTextField setStringValue:textValue];
}
```

The problem is that I can update `resaultText` and have access to the value of this. But `cbxDataList` value is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use retain instead of assign to increase the retain count of cbxDataList.

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray   *cbxDataList;
```

Please note, that the object needs to be released sometime, or you could have a memory leak.

Comment: this is not the answer..!!

Comment: Tnx for answer. It's working with some more changes:
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.baseDataEntity cbxDataList]];

Answer (score 0):

In the below function,

```
-(void)updateUserInterface:(BOOL)piClear
```

The array creation is wrong.

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:
        [self.baseDataEntity.cbxDataList value]];
```

The above code nneeds to be replaced by,

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:
        self.baseDataEntity.cbxDataList];
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it later. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try these :

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *cbxDataList; 
@property (assign) NSString  *resaultText;
```

And in `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

alloc+init both of them.